# What is the remoteurl parameter for docusign

Tags: docusignapi

Is the fileid specific to the storage provider (googledrive, dropbox, box, or onedrive)? Or, is this something that docusign generates when you share your storage provider with them?

Comment: Where are you seeing the option for `remoteurl`?  Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the DocuSign documentation [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm), the remoteUrl seems to be specific to the cloud storage provider. See below the official description of the "remoteUrl" parameter:

*remoteUrl  String

The file id from the cloud storage service where the document is located. This information is returned using GET /folders or /folders/{folderid}.*

Also, the documentation (see [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Get%20User%20Items%20in%20one%20Cloud%20Storage%20Provider%20Folder.htm)) goes further and explains how to retrieve a list of all items in all folders for the user from the selected cloud storage provider.